# Electron/NodeJS Connecting to SQL Server using mssql not working

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm new to Electron and trying to make 1 st application in which I need to connect it to a SQL server database for data storing/retrieving. I've have installed this plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connect-callback) and followed their instructions but got no success regarding the connection. The weird part is that I also get no error or whatever showing in the console so I'm totally lost. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you guys.

Ps: I'm sure that there's no problem with the database since I can still connect to it using the same config setting below with a database client manager tool.

Below is the code I've used for simple testing connection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const electron = require('electron');
            const sql = require('mssql');
            const config = {
                user: 'ql*****',
                password: 'qlh****',
                server: '123.20.****',
                database: 'QLHS'
            };
            async () => {
                try {
                    await sql.connect(config);
                    const result = await sql.query`select * from DM_DONVI`;
                    console.dir(result);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            };
        });  
    </script>
```

Comment: You are trying to connect to mysql from javascript (front-end). Learn more about Nodejs and Electron.

Comment: @EdwinBabu thank Edwin, but this seems to be the case with a lot of examples on the Internet I could find. For example, in this one (though they're not working with sql server but mysql), the author also did implement the connection in the html file. https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/259/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-electron-framework

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/259/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-electron-framework) you provided is working. I tried the same. The error log can be seen in view->Toogle Developer Tools. The issue is you need install mysql.

```
npm install mysql --save
```

Then the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr :D Actually, the thing that didn't work in my original post is the async part. Changing that to this and everything is fine now:

```
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        var request = new sql.Request();

        request.query('select * from DM_DONVI', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Something went wrong")
            }
            else {
                var result = JSON.stringify(recordset);
                console.log(recordset.recordsets[0]);
            }
        });
});
```